# How to exclude particular cells from a range in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, sumifs

I'm trying to count the SUM of the range under condition like the range eg. between 2021 M01 and 2022 M02, but I want to exclude TOTAL values (2021 TOTAL, 2022 TOTAL and 2023 TOTAL) from my formula. How can I do that

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just add the condition to your `SUMIFS()`:

[image]

Formula in `B5`:

```
=SUMIFS(5:5,4:4,">="&B2,4:4,"<="&C2,4:4,"<>* TOTAL")
```